# How to I use the random image option on bxSlider plugin for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I have tried several times to use the random image option on the jQuery slider plugin bxSlider but can't seem to figure it out.

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 as required for my homework for a js/jQuery class.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carousel with bxSlider</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-
    1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").bxSlider({
            displaySlideQty: 1,
            moveSlideQty: 1,
            default: false,
            options: (true/false)




            }
        );
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <section>
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>On June 6th, 2012, Vecta Corp. moved into its new 4 story, 35,000 
    square foot facilty. Below are a few pictures of the new facility.</p>
    <p id="caption"></p>
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="images/building_01_thumb.jpg" title="Front of 
    building" width="200"></li>
        <li><img src="images/building_02_thumb.jpg" title="Left side of 
    building" width="200"></li>
        <li><img src="images/building_03_thumb.jpg" title="Rear of building" 
    width="200"></li>
        <li><img src="images/building_04_thumb.jpg" title="Offices" 
    width="200"></li>
        <li><img src="images/building_05_thumb.jpg" title="Conference room" 
    width="200"></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="pager"></p>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try to read documentation more carefully and not just doing copy/paste. `randomStart` options are true or false so you need to set it like `randomStart: true`

Comment: Ok. After I pasted, I tabbed the code 4 spaces indented. Is there anything that I did wrong that I needed to correct so that I can post better? Thanks for the input jakob. The randomStart option works great!

Comment: I dont understand what you asked in comment but if `randomStart` works then it is solved right?

Comment: Yes, it is solved. Thanks again!